# When memory errors occur with model.fit(), is it due to GPU RAM or normal RAM?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, gpu

With respect to this question,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895278/how-to-know-when-to-use-fit-generator-in-keras-when-training-data-gets-too-big

when memory errors are reported due to excessively large training data, are the memory errors caused by lack of normal PC RAM or lack of GPU RAM? I would like to know which one so that I can buy the right kind of RAM.

Keras was configured to use GPU for training.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The error is for GPU memory. You should look at training in batches options if you haven't already. [This](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12532/does-batch-size-in-keras-have-any-effects-in-results-quality) thread has short explanation on possible benefits and implications.

Quick batch size [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-different-batch-sizes-training-predicting-python-keras/)